# Should there really be 1 MΩ resistance between an anti-static wrist strap and a pc?

Tags: grounding, esd, ground-plane, antistatic, static-electricity

My previous question: [what exactly is grounded through motherboard standoffs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1138512/what-exactly-is-grounded-through-motherboard-standoffs)

The answers suggest that a PC case is grounded in 2 ways:

1. To the ground plane of the motherboard, through the brass standoffs.

   - The ground plane is grounded to the PSU, through the ground wires from the 24-pin power connector.
2. To the PSU case, through screws. (Or surface-to-surface if PC case and PSU case are both unpainted.)

   - The PSU case and internals are grounded to the earth prong.

> Q1: Is this correct so far?

OEMs like DELL advise to ["touch an unpainted metal surface."](https://youtu.be/bxugZ4cyf3Q?t=1m24s) Thus, when you touch the case, you are directly bonding with:

- case
- standoffs
- ground plane of the motherboard

But when you attach your anti-static wrist strap to the case, there is a 1MΩ resistance between you and the case, because of the 1MΩ resistor in practically every coil cord that comes with a wrist strap.

So, apparently, touching the case, without a resistor, is fine. But a wrist strap should be bonded through a resistor. That's contradictory.

> Q2: Can bonding to the case, through a coil cord without a resistor, do any harm to hardware components?

Comment: I wouldn't say its contradictory, I'd say its complementary. Its ok to bound directly, it is better to discharge in a controlled manner (i.e. resistor). It could also protect the user of a wristband in case he/she/it gets shocked.

Comment: It can be pretty unpleasant to discharge 25kV potential over a low resistance path...

Comment: AFAIK the resistor is there to protect the hardware from ESD-damage, not the user.

Comment: I'd say the user is more important than the hardware..

Comment: Haha, my main concern is the hardware. I can handle a little shock. I think there's little voltage to worry about, after turning off the PSU and making sure only the earth-prong is connected to earth directly or via a common ground point.

Comment: I think you are looking this too much from the computer maintenance perspective. ESD straps have much broader usage, and although the resistor may not make much sense to you in your application, it certainly is welcome in the other scenarios.

Comment: If you electrocute yourself whilst holding a good earth point, or with a good earth point physically connected to one wrist, you have a good chance of serious death. Its fun to watch you argue against people who know this.

Comment: Note that the amount of static charge on your body is miniscule when compared to common electric currents. That's why a 1M resistor is still good enough to discharge that small amount quickly (ms?) and there's no need to discharge instantly through a high but short (µs?) current pulse.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane as opposed to a death that is casual or lighthearted?

Comment: If the deceased hair stands on end or smokes it would be lighthearted.  If they make comedy convulsions too.  It stops being funny when they stop moving though.

Comment: I don't see how i would electrocute myself holding a good earth point. Because then i would also die whenever i would walk outside on bare feet. And that never happened to me... yet.

Comment: @Marty "I don't see how i would electrocute myself holding a good earth point. Because then i would also die whenever i would walk outside on bare feet." If you read carefully the article about Earth Potential Rise I linked to in my answer, you'll discover that you could be killed just by walking outside, if you were standing where a fault current entered ground (e.g. near the point where a broken high voltage line touched ground) if your two feet were at a sufficient distance between each other (without the need to directly touch the broken dangling live wire!).

Comment: @Marty - It's not that you could be electrocuted by having your wrist directly attached to a ground point (without a resistor). The resistor is meant to provide protection in situations like this: Your left wrist is attached to ground through the wrist strap, without a resistor. You reach with your right hand and inadvertently touch a live circuit. Without the resistor, you could be seriously injured or killed. With the resistor, you'll probably just say hmm, what was that?, or maybe oh, that didn't feel good.

Comment: @Marty Electrocute yourself ***while*** holding a good earth point. Not ***by*** holding one.

Comment: I often rely on my 1MOhm finger tip to see if the 120Vac is live when re-wiring, knowing if I am careful, it's only 160uA peak but pressure to a sharp wire tip quickly drops 1M to 50k, old electricians, still,alive will say they use the insulation resistance of saliva on 3kV to test circuits with a burning test wet finger. and I recall our Grade X shop teacher telling some newbie who asked, Can I touch this wire? He said yes, other said ouch, he replied U said " can I? "you didn't ask , "should I?"

Answer (score 21):

The 1meg resistor is needed to safeguard the user from faults from other equipment connected to mains earth.

Keep in mind that the wrist strap is a permanent connection to the electric system of the building. If another piece of equipment experiences a fault, there could be a big fault current through the mains earth wiring system. That means that, in unfortunate circumstances, the mains earth terminal could reach a dangerous potential. In this case, the 1Meg resistor limits the current *from the earth wire trough the user* to a safe limit.

See this [Wikipedia article about Earth Potential Rise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_potential_rise), for example.

Excerpt:

> The resistance of the Earth is non-zero, so current injected into the earth at the grounding electrode produces a potential rise with respect to a distant reference point. The resulting potential rise can cause hazardous voltage, many hundreds of meters away from the actual fault location.

Therefore the earth wiring system (and your wrist), due to its low resistance, is roughly at the same potential of the point where the fault current enters ground, whereas your feet (several hundred meters away from that point) are at a lower potential. Without that 1Meg resistor: ***ZAPP!!!***

**EDIT** (to address downvoting and clarify my answer)

Since my answer has attracted a couple of down-votes and some criticism in the comments (not necessarily related, at least not apparently) I feel compelled to clarify something, but I'd like also to remind downvoters what down votes are for: for answers that are not useful, not on topic or plainly wrong.

**First:** I was told that regulation doesn't require the 1Meg resistor for the reasons I stated. My answer: I never stated that my explanation was related to some regulation (I didn't even know there was a specific regulation for wrist bands - BTW, I'd like to see some reference), but I concede I could have been more explicit.

**Second:** As I wrote in a comment, I admit that my scenario is less likely than, for example, touching a live wire or an ESD event whose rapid discharge could cause issues. Nevertheless, as someone said in a comment, ***You only die once!*** Faults in electric systems **do** happen, and often they are not under **your** control, so no level of care **from your side** could prevent them, you can only (try to) prevent the consequences. Hence the scenario I depicted is, IMO, well worth considering (so it is on-topic and it is useful). Moreover, the question in the title is *Should there really be 1 MΩ resistance between an anti-static wrist strap and a pc?*, not something like *Why regulations impose a resistor there?* or *What's the most likely scenario that resistor is put there for?*.

To further make my point you can see this [article on Wikipedia about Stray Voltages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stray_voltage). Not everything is directly related to what I'm saying, but the part on [Neutral return currents through the ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stray_voltage#Neutral_return_currents_through_the_ground) is. Excerpt (emphasis mine):

> Stray voltage became a problem for the dairy industry some time after electric milking machines were introduced, and **large numbers of animals were simultaneously in contact with metal objects grounded to the electric distribution system and the earth**. Numerous studies document the causes,[11] physiological effects,[12] and prevention,[13][14] of stray voltage in the farm environment. Today, stray voltage on farms is regulated by state governments and controlled by the design of equipotential planes in areas where livestock eat, drink or give milk. Commercially available neutral isolators also prevent elevated potentials on the utility system neutral from **raising the voltage of farm neutral or ground wires**.

(I didn't have the time to search for an article involving grounded humans instead of grounded cows, but you get the point.)

Bottom line: *connecting a human body to any low-impedance path that could possibly rise in potential **is dangerous** and **life threatening***, so proper safety measures should be in place.

Comment: Let's say, first you ground the earth-prong from the PSU to a common ground point , with no resistor in between. Then you ground your wrist strap to the same common ground point; also no resistor in between. How could you possible get a shock?

Comment: The shock could come from another power source: a gross fault current in another part of the building (extreme case: imagine your building is hit by a lightning). The mains earth potential could rise and the voltage between your feet and your wrist could be several hundreds volts!

Comment: Surely a more likely hazard is that you touch something live with the other hand (or a tool in the other hand); that 1M limits the current through you on a particularly dangerous path.

Comment: @ChrisH Thats also a possibility, but wrist bands are used also during maintenance and testing of equipment and circuits that aren't connected to any power source. Anyway that 1Meg resistor should protect you from the unknown: you can do something for powered circuits just being careful, you don't have any control on remote fault currents, instead. Beware: I'm not saying that mistakes don't happen, but at least being careful helps. No level of care could protect you if a 100kW motor has a gross fault in the workshop downstairs!

Comment: @Marty as for realistic scenarios: think of it as something like safety belts. You can be the most careful driver, but if a drunken truck driver falls asleep while driving his 100ton truck in the opposite lane, you *may* end up thanking the designers (and the law) who provided you with those belts!

Comment: @Marty if you attach the strap to the *unearthed* case and the equipment is not powered, you *maybe* could do without that resistor (ESD wise). But a reputable manufacturer wouldn't sell one without: it costs almost nothing and protect the user in the worst case.

Comment: Okay! My thoughts were that no resistor would be necessary, because people touch the inside of their case often with bare hands and i never heard of someone getting a shock. I am primarily concerned about ESD damage to my hardware. Not about myself. While not feeling a zapp myself, the hardware may exactly feel it, because it's so sensitive. I'm still wondering why "touching the case" to bond yourself with the ground-plane of the motherboard is common practice. Even large OEMs like DELL advice it.

Comment: @Lorenzo, there are plenty of safety measures required for plenty of hazards when working with potentially live equipment. Not having a low-impedance path to ground on the off hand is a major one. More often than not if I'm taking anti static precautions there's no power, but if I power up the kit for testing the wrist strap shouldn't introduce a hazard. I think we're in broad agreement

Comment: @Marty keep in mind that  *you could* get killed even by an unpowered PC, if the main capacitors (charged at hundreds of volts) in the switching power supply are still retaining enough energy. Usually there should be circuitry to avoid that charge retention for long time (bleeder resistors, or more complex and efficient circuitry), but you never know!

Comment: @ChrisH Yep! And I'd like to point out, for the people at large, that without that resistor you could be at risk even with your equipment completely disconnected from the electrical system, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: For years, before removing or installing memory modules or hard drives, i would just remove the cables, unplug the power cable and touch unpainted metal of the case. So for year i was actually playing with my life? And many others with me? Because this method is common practice.

Comment: @Marty IIRC until end of 70s in Italy safety belts were not even mandatory in Italy (and cars sold at that time weren't even equipped with them). It was common practice. The same could be said for Ground Fault Interrupters (differential breakers): they weren't mandatory in households until mid 80s. It was common practice not to install them...

Comment: @Marty ...As a nerdy teenager I worked in my "home lab" on mains-powered equipment without proper safety measures (I was *VERY* careful, and the worst it happened was some minor electric shocks once in a long while): it was *my* common practice. I would never recommend this to my students today! Bottom line: there are lots of common practices that are potentially dangerous. Legislation and technical culture evolve with time. Nowadays some laws prohibit practices that were common 20 something years ago: just to save a "small" number of lives.

Comment: To accentuate Lorenzo's last point in his answer -- if you don't protect yourself, you could end up like [this poor guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapp_Brannigan) ;)

Comment: @Marty: You could have been in trouble if there was a fault in the PSU which allowed the high voltage accumulated on the capacitors to reach the low-voltage output pins.  Any fault of that type would have fried the entire computer, logic boards are not designed to have lethal-to-you voltages applied on their input power connector.

Comment: @Marty "But is that a realistic scenario" - In real life you only die once. You don't get to restart the game and try again if you screw up the first time.

Comment: @Marty The key difference is that when doing maintenance, you touch the case *once*, and ideally, it is disconnected from the mains at that point in time. Whereas a anti-static wrist strap is connected to your body for hours in a row. A lot can happen in these hours, like touching a live circuit or surprise lightning strike or any other Earth Potential Rise cases. This may not be common in PC maintenance, but it is in *many* other applications of anti-static wrist straps, and the 1 MΩ protects against electrocution in these cases.

Comment: To the downvoter: would you care to explain what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: The biggest problem with your scenario is that you are assuming that the user is *also* grounded by some other independent means -- it's the only way that a rise in the mains ground potential could be at all dangerous. The *stated reason* for the resistor in the regulations is to limit the current should the user touch a live terminal in the equipment on which he's working.

Comment: @DaveTweed His feet are somewhat "grounded", unless he is wearing insulated shoes or the floor is covered with insulating material. Unless the OP works in a highly electrically-safe environment (e.g. industrial labs), this is unlikely (and in my experience repair shops aren't so safe usually).  I didn't talk about specific regulations concerning that resistor, although I concede that my scenario is less likely than an accidental contact with a live terminal. Nevertheless, it is a possible scenario, and not one to be dismissed as unlikely or impossible.

Comment: It is not Wrong to safeguard humans from electrocution but when working on electronics, you are more likely to create large discharge currents if you touch statically charged floating equipment while working on sensitive equipment exposed , so although not wrong to say it protects humans, the more probable risk is high current paths to EOS pins and parts and thus current limiting is essential for the parts, and also protects humans from unlikely but possible ground currents, that may be 10's of volts not necessarily live but possible, but rare. This is MY experience ONLY.

Answer (score 8):

You have two questions which you think are related since they both concern ground connections. However the questions are not related !

Q1) The actual ground connection, where the return current from the supply flows, are the **black** wires on the ATX power connector. Indeed the chassis is also connected to the motherboard via the screws but this connection is not essential for normal operation. You can also use a motherboard without this connenction, for example when testing it before mounting in a case.

But the ATX connection **is** essential. The ATX power supply then provides the connection to the ground in your mains sockets.

Q2) This is for ESD discharge, almost no power needs to flow as it only concerns balancing of charge levels. Sudden ESD discharges can damage components. A 1 Mohm resistor is a low enough resistance to allow for the balancing of charge levels.

So the 1 Mohm resistor does not hinder in any way the ESD protection !

It does provide extra safety. If that 1 Mohm resistor was not there and you would touch a live voltage (like mains voltage) a current will easily flow through you and the wristband. The current can then reach dangerous levels ! That 1 Mohm resistor in series increases the resistance of this path to a safe level. If you touched a live wire you could feel a "tingle" but the current cannot reach a dangerous level due to the resistor.

So: the resistor is a safety measure to protect the user, which is you !

Comment: Well, Q1 goes prior to Q2. Because if the case is not directly bonded to the ground-plane, then Q2 isn't relevant.

Comment: *Because if the case is not directly bonded to the ground-plane, then Q2 isn't relevant* I disagree ! The groundstrap prevent your body from building up a charge which could discharge through an ESD sensitive device on the motherboard. Have a look at a professional PC building facility and you will see both PCs grounded **and** the workers wearing wrist straps or conductive shoes on a conductive floor !

Comment: *But does it promote ESD-protection?* I do not understand what you mean. A wrist-strap does help with ESD protection though.

Comment: The PC does not have to be grounded when working inside but any external wires if floating can create a floating charge and arc externally. The main reason they say to keep grounded via power plug is to eliminate this uncertainty. But we EE's who are EOS aware, understand you only need to null the potential difference to the case.

Comment: 100k is deemed too low by ESD/EOS experts due to std voltage and current limits and >>10M is deemed too high for dissipation time constant therefore the it is standardized as 1M. Neither wrist strap and foot strap is a guarantee. *I recall a Tek Fet buffered diff probe that junior engineers used to blow with 25V max 10uA ratings , just by looking the wrong way with the shorting tips removed lol*

Answer (score 5):

**EOS/ESD prevention Experience**

The reason for the acceptable range of 1M to 10 M is to current limit static discharge for wrist straps.  in addition it reduces current to live voltages.

---

--- added

> ***Although Vac line voltage both IEC/UL acceptable leakage is 500uA for line filters etc, so one could reason that the wrist strap could be reduced to 240k with the same safe limit, but not for EOS sensitive parts. So you could say for both reasons, but the primary reason for protection is the EOS sensitive parts, otherwise why not 10M? or 22M or 50M? ***  That would be safer for humans, but that is not the main purpose of an "EOS protected workplace", but workplace safety is also important.

---

- It does this by bleeding body charge slowly to the same potential of the case or gnd reference that the 1M resistor is clamped to, while static charge may be generated by motion or change in body capacitance with a fixed charge, V=C/Q .

> - Thus for example, consider a 10000 pf body surface to stray air charged at 10kV   then connected  to a 1M current limiting resistor, we might expect 10k/1M or 10mA with a decay time of 1M*10nF=10ms which is faster than pre-ionization time, so the resistor might be bypassed. But with it connected all the time, the rate of charge build up dV/dt is much slower than the discharge time so body charge levels are kept at relatively low levels.

- meanwhile the finger tip model of 100-300pF * 1M = 100u-300us decay time keeps fingers with wrist straps to ground discharged faster from tribe-electric effects and thus momentary charge build up of 1kV is limited to 1mA.

  > to verify this understanding yourself, recall the current zap you heard with a key or finger to metal ESD discharge and compare your experience touching a grounded tree (not paint or plastic) due to surface resistance, you likely would not feel anything and yet this can be enough to damage unprotected microwave FETs with 25V BDV, but your experience tells you the series surface resistance limited the current.

For Electrostatic Over Stress or EOS prevention all surfaces must be "Static Dissipative" to prevent rapid discharge.

The other reason is to reduce the potential ionization discharge time from 5-100 picoseconds that creates E-Field transients faster than the ESD diodes can response when CMOS inputs are connected to long cables (antenna).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDY3W4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the same reasons flooring and work surfaces need to \$10^{10}\$ Ohms per square.

- It is well known that e-field discharges in one place may conduct via a long ground path and radiate from this path to damage very sensitive parts from the resulting antenna efficiency of interconnects to sensitive parts at frequencies dependant on the rise time of the discharge.
- I have seen photos and many journal researchers validate that finger ESD may have a current transition time down to 5-10ps which has been captured. This translates to a continuous Fourier Spectrum of at least f=1/3t or roughly 25-50GHz which has a corresponding very short wavelength at the upper range.

> So effectively any length can capture some of the transient Field and thus is EOS unsafe.  We rate parts only with 100pF or 300F for Human finger  capacitance due to the tiny area of contact. But in reality, between two hands we can measure with an RLC meter and "good contact area" with probes 100x more capacitance easily.  Thus ESD generated by walking on dry dusty floors or hotel nylon carpets with key can generate a healthy arc of 30kV or ~3cm and a good zap and radiate within the entire room.  Due to RF properties & physics, one cannot guarantee to zap any unprotected Semi, nor can you guarantee that it is not "wounded" a similar breakdown ratio in kV/mm now attenuated to small levels and distances but only slightly higher ratios of mV/nm in charged dielectric junction BreakDown Voltages (BDV) spanning xx nm.
>
> This is also a future limitation for Moore's Law Lithography shrinkage in CPU's. If the junctions got much smaller,  it can approach BDV levels of Silicon in xx mV/nm ratings.
>
> - It is also a huge challenge for semiconductor Prcoess Engineers to avoid ESD in the fabrication of semiconductors with triboelectrically charged material e.g. Silicon and Gallium Arsenside vapours superheated being deposited on junctions

- A risky but effective alternative when a wrist strap is not available, is to be aware of triboelectric surfaces , discharge surfaces and all static sensitive devices and touch fingers while holding a PCB ground tab before handing it to the other person.
- OR, always keep one finger at least on a PC case so to remain at the same E field strength as the PCB inside grounded to the case, when changing parts.
- OR to gently touch a grounded surface away with your 1M "calibrated" finger tip (using DMM or RLC) and don't touch your breadboard before doing this, then be aware how easy E fields can be created.
- In my past 40 yrs experience before I implemented EOS prevention in the electronics factory, I can tell you how easy it was to reset a Motorola Emulator or an Apple ][ just from ESD 10m away. The lab was surrounded by a grounded cage (antenna) and at time in the 80's nylon commercial carpet made great ESD generators with neoprene soled shoes. (salty leather is better)

Most MOBO's use insulated standoffs, and a few use conductive, so Ground connection is thru DC plug to ATX PSU to case ground, where ground is local reference to case. WHen connected to Power outlet, the local case ground is connected to earth ground thru household wiring, but very inductive , so the case is the best shield.

( except for long IO cables , special case beware they can carry ESD charges from tribo-electric friction)

**- example** When I was TE Mgr, technicians would drag 10m SCSI cables on dry  concrete floor ( with dust) and connect to towers in Final Test and blow SCSI drivers from ESD, until we trained them to touch Connector shell and frame before connection.

Comment: But then why is [touching with bare hands](https://youtu.be/bxugZ4cyf3Q?t=1m24s) okay? That certainly is not "bonding in a dissipative manner", is it?

Comment: @Marty touching the components with bare hands is a bad idea, until you've ensured you're at the same potential as the ground they're connected to.  Whether you equalise potentials  with or without a wrist strap doesn't actually make a huge amount of difference in the case of a PC with a big metal box well-connected to ground.

Comment: In [the video](https://youtu.be/bxugZ4cyf3Q?t=55s) you can see the PSU of that particular PC being disconnected from mains power. As a result the earth prong is also being disconnected from mains earth. Thus **the ground-plane of the motherboard is not grounded to earth anymore**. Still DELL advices to ["touch unpainted metal surface on your computer"](https://youtu.be/bxugZ4cyf3Q?t=1m24s). Thus, apparently, touching an unpainted part of the case with bare hands is okay.

Comment: I once charged a 5MVA transformer winding to 50kV then gradually up to 150kV dc. The epoxy paint produced ESD discharges to my finger on contact to every outer surface area like a charge cloud and only discharged a tiny zone of paint.,.thus is further proof, painted surfaces are not good. (unless carbon filled epoxy)  Even ESD can break thru the paint while charging up the entire surface creating a larger mJ of energy discharge from higher current which results in lower ESR of the ionization arc. Maxwell proved this.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yes, if the potential is high enough, then it can break thru a layer of paint. Then again, if the layer is very thick, the potential should be even higher. But my question is: can i damage ICs on my ATX motherboard, by touching the case, or not. In the video, DELL is advising to touch the case in order to bond with it. I guess, to bond with the ground-plane of the motherboard. Can this do harm to the motherboard?

Comment: @Marty Yes AS I explained in my answer (Dell is correct) You are safe to touch the case due to "faraday cage effect" of design.... but beware that if case is not grounded I/O driver receivers may be exposed to some transient (al beit somewhat protected) unless grounded on I/O or thru VGA port to monitor etc.  THe best practice is touch case with finger tip (1M~10M approx) Then any loose hand connection keeps you at same potential as board.  Calibrate your fingertip for self awareness

Comment: The first few paragraphs of this answer are completely wrong. The ground strap resistor is in the wrong place in the circuit to have any effect on either the current or the risetime of an ESD event, which occurs directly between the human's body capacitance and the part being touched.

Comment: Maybe I mis wrote it, but I assure you I understand completely,  1MOhm limits current and bleeds charge slowly unless there is an arc across the resistor. Touching the finger will create an arc but to the Faraday shielded case, is a "100 -300pF capacitor model" with discharge of safe levels touching the case only.  feel free to edit

Comment: Dave if you feel so strongly about "completely wrong" be prepared to back it up and let's chat. I think you misunderstood, what I wrote, which may be grammatically incorrect, or explained with too much brevity?

Answer (score 4):

"Touching with bare hands" will MOMENTARILY DISCHARGE your body PRIOR to handling any static-sensitive objects (boards, chips, etc.)  Using a wrist-strap will CONTINUOUSLY drain any static charge and keep you safe from zapping anything you touch.

If you could do whatever with one hand, then touching the case of the computer accomplishes essentially the same thing as using a wrist-strap except that YOU are NOT protected from electrocution as you would be from a proper static-dissipative wrist strap.

Comment: Yes, "touching with bare hands" will discharge you while touching, but will not keep you discharged. You'll have to hold on to the case continuously or you'll have to attach your anti-static wrist strap to the case to keep yourself bonded to the ground-plane of the motherboard. My question: should there be 1E6 resistance in the coil cord between you and the case? (Given the scenario that the PC isn't grounded to mains earth anymore.)

Comment: YES, there should be a 1M resistance. Because that is plenty to keep static discharged, but not enough to put you at risk of electrocution.  Remember that you CANNOT assume that the case is not grounded to mains.  There aren't separate wrist straps for "isolated" and "lucky".

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answers! One more thing: i can assume or even know for sure that the case is not grounded to mains earth when i unplug all the cables :-)

Comment: Clearly, if there are ZERO cables connected and it isn't sitting on a grounded surface, then the chassis is not grounded. But the question seems odd as you should NOT depend on that. That is why there is a resistance in the wrist strap.  The issue isn't discharging static to earth ground. The issue is eliminating the DIFFERENTIAL between YOU and the chassis.

Comment: Exactly! Zero potential between me and the chassis, which is the case, which is bonded to the ground-plane of the motherboard. So, zero potential between me and the ground-plane. [DELL advices to put the case on a table and unplug all the cables](https://youtu.be/bxugZ4cyf3Q?t=55s). Then touch an unpainted part of the case, to equalize the charge.

Comment: But, in the scenario above, [like in the DELL video](https://youtu.be/bxugZ4cyf3Q?t=1m24s), when i attach my wrist strap to the case, instead of continuously touching it. Then should there be 1E6 resistance in the coil cord?

Comment: YES, to protect YOU from electrocution!!! Unless you feel particularly lucky and have good insurance.

Comment: Touching an unpainted part of the case, with bare hands, is fine, but attaching my wrist strap to the same spot on the case, without a resistor in the coil cord, could get me electrocuted?

Comment: Touching the case could also get you electrocuted, but not through a 1M resistor. If you feel suicidal go ahead and use a direct connection.  Those of us who have worked around electricity for a few decades have much more respect for it.

Comment: [Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds](https://youtu.be/bxugZ4cyf3Q?t=1m), like DELL advices, is not enough to discharge the PC prior to touching the case?

Comment: I don't see how "press and hold" the power button discharges anything. The button is plastic, non-conductive.  It is not the PC that is "charged" is the DIFFERENTIAL between YOU and the PC that is the source of danger.  The video properly observes that the issue is equalizing the potential between YOU and the case of the PC.  It really has nothing to do with "ground" in the traditional mains-power sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47509/discussion-between-marty-and-richard-crowley).

Comment: So the question is: *"Do you feel lucky?"*

Comment: @Marty "_Touching an unpainted part of the case, with bare hands, is fine, but attaching my wrist strap to the same spot on the case, without a resistor in the coil cord, could get me electrocuted?_" Touching may not be fine if _at that instant_ something unlikely-but-horrible went wrong, but because it's only for an instant, you're _probably_ fine. The difference with a wriststrap is "that instant" is extended into "permanently", so if anything nasty happens, you wouldn't be protected without the resistor.

Comment: When the power cable is unplugged from the PSU, can there really be a lot of charge left? I would think of only a few capacitors, which are slowly discharging until everything (motherboard, CPU, memory, graphics card, etc.) is at the same potential. How long would that take? A few seconds? After that, can you touch the inside of the ATX case safely?

Comment: You keep confusing charge on the power components with electrostatic charge from the environment. THOSE ARE TWO COMPLETELY DIFFERENT THINGS THAT HAVE NOTHING TO DO WITH EACH OTHER!  YOU ARE MASSIVELY CONFUSED.

Comment: Could you explain further? My thoughts: after i shut down my PC, the capacitors on the motherboard will drain to earth potential, because of the ground wire in the power cable. The capacitors in the PSU are being discharged by bleeder resistors. Yes, i'm assuming a perfect world: no earth potential rise and no faulty PSU. In that perfect world, ESD is caused by the potential difference between me and the PC, right?

Comment: I like to think about 2 ESD models: HBM (Human Body Model) and CDM (Charged Device Model). HBM: i touch a device, like a ATX motherboard. CDM: 2 devices make contact, like a graphics card entering a PCIe x16 slot. Probably there is a potential difference. So, current starts to flow for a few milliseconds, until the potential difference is equalized. During these milliseconds, there could be more current going thru internal circuitry then they can handle. The ICs literally fry. This can be noticed immediately, because the PC won't boot, or after some period of time.

Comment: In the perfect world (no earth potential rise and no faulty PSU) can i cause ESD-damage to my motherboard by touching the case directly, without resistor in between, when there is a potential difference between me and the motherboard?

Comment: @Marty, The capacitors in the computer (on the motherboard or in the PSU) will NOT drain through the power cable.  The external ground connection plays NO PART in the power circuit INSIDE the computer.  Half the portable computers in the world use 2-wire power cables and have NO GROUND connection at all.  Yet they clearly discharge after the power is turned off.  You are still confusing the low voltage, high current internal power circuits with external static discharge. THESE HAVE **NOTHING** TO DO WITH EACH OTHER!!!!!!

Comment: @Marty, we don't know what is "earth potential rise"???  You can cause damage to chips, modules, or or boards without any PSU at all.  The PSU has NOTHING to do with ESD!  If the motherboard is properly secured to the metal case, then discharging to the case is typically safe because the case equalizes the charge before it reaches the motherboard (or other active components).

Comment: @RichardCrowley, I was thinking the motherboard-caps would drain to earth, because of the comments i got on [my previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/1138512/what-exactly-is-grounded-through-motherboard-standoffs). I had [the assumption that the case, ground-plane and earth prong on the PSU are directly connected to earth](http://superuser.com/questions/1138512/what-exactly-is-grounded-through-motherboard-standoffs#comment1634165_1138514). Therefore i thought the mobo-caps would drain until the potential difference between those caps and earth is equalized.

Comment: @RichardCrowley, in the answers, [Lorenzo Donati pointed out that you shouldn't connect your wrist strap to mains earth without a resistor in between](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/265924/127725), because you can't be sure there is absolutely no [earth potential rise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_potential_rise).

Comment: @RichardCrowley, i wasn't referring to the PSU as a possible cause of ESD-damage. You said that PSU-caps could be dangerous to the user. I just proposed a perfect world, in which the PSU-caps would drain, because of the bleeder resistors. Then i asked: can i cause ESD-damage to my motherboard by touching my unpainted case, which is bonded to the ground-plane of my motherboard?

Comment: @Marty, The INPUT capacitors in a SMPS could be "dangerous to the user" until (internally) discharged, although I never mentioned that before. But that has nothing to do with ESD. As I explained above, the conductive metal case will equalize any ESD so that it will pose no threat to the motherboard.  The only thing potentially dangerous to the user is a wrist-strap WITHOUT a 1M resistor because it increases the risk of electrocution from the power mains. Nothing to do with ESD.